# How many records in the database have NULL values in any of these columns: genre, purchase date, production year. You are looking for a single number

Tags: sql, oracle

> How many records in the database have NULL values in any of these columns: genre, purchase date, production year. You are looking for a single number.

Hey guys I'm wondering how I would add the nulls together in a single number. using is null will just show me how many nulls there are.

Comment: Tip: how many nulls are there in column1 OR in column2

Comment: Is the old record database still around...? I had that when I studied too, a very, very long time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `SELECT` can easily do this, eg:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TableName
WHERE ("genre" IS NULL)
OR ("purchase date" IS NULL)
OR ("production year" IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the accepted answer is correct but still giving answer for knowledge.

You can use `SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL` which is another way to compare nulls. It can be used when you want one null to be equal to other null (`null = null`).

You can use it in your query as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM TableName
 WHERE SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL(NULL) IN
       (SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL("genre"),
        SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL("purchase date"),
        SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL("production year"));
```